# Django show different forms if creating or updating a model

Tags: django, forms, django-class-based-views

I have a forms.py that show a dropdown when creating. But I would like it to be a hidden field when updating. Is it possible to make forms.py show 2 different views depending on you are creating or updating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create multiple forms for your different needs (e.g. one for creation, one for update). Because you might have fields in common, you can do class inheritance.

```
class ParentAbstractForm():
    #define common fields here

class CreationForm(ParentAbstractForm)
    # specific fields

class UpdateForm(ParentAbstractForm)
    # specific fields
```

Comment: Or you pass a flag into the form and add or modify the form field dynamically. You will need two different views anyway.

Comment: @Tiino Well what you say is correct, but your example code doesn't do any inheritance, it just has a class as an attribute for another class.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat response has been updated. Thanks

Comment: This answer doesn't actually specify how to register that one form should be used for creation and another for editing, not sure why it's been accepted?